# Problema armando $or con regexMatch en MongoDB en C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, dotnetcore

Como estan? Estoy teniendo un problema con un aggregation de MongoDB.
Tengo toda una consulta que voy armando segun unos parametros. En uno de esos parametros necesito pasar un $or que indique que alguno de los siguientes tres campos tenga un valor like % filtro % (como haria SQL). Entiendo que debo usar regexMatch pero no estoy seguro.
El problema es que es como si esos filtros no afectaran en nada la consulta ya que me trae siempre todos los registros y no tira ningun error.

Alguien me podria indicar que estoy haciendo mal?
Gracias!

```
filterFiltro = @", $or: [ 
                          { $expr: { regexMatch: {  input: 'Numero',  regex: '/" + filtro + @"/'  } } },
                          { $expr: { regexMatch: {  input: 'Punto',   regex: '/" + filtro + @"/'  } } },
                          { $expr: { regexMatch: {  input: 'Tipo',    regex: '/" + filtro + @"/'  } } }
                        ]";


string json = @"[  
                {
                    $match: {
                                IDUsuario: {  $gt: 0 }"
                                + filterFiltro <----- ESTE ES EL $or
                                + @"
                            }
                },    
                { 
                    $sort: {
                                'RazonSocial': -1  
                           }
                }, "
                + groupByAgreg + @"
                { 
                    $project: { _id: 0 }
                }
            ]";
```